# Specific example of conditional MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I have a table called "budgets" with data about our sales budget for different countries for each month.

I need to create a conditional query, that pulls the budget data for each country for the given month.

If the budget for a specific country has not been added yet, the query should return the budget of the previous month (which will always exist).

```
  country   | date       | budget
===================================
| Argentina | 2018-02-01 | $100
| Brazil    | 2018-02-01 | $350
| Brazil    | 2018-03-01 | $430
| Colombia  | 2018-02-01 | $100
| Chile     | 2018-02-01 | $100
| Chile     | 2018-03-01 | $75
```

Example:

If we pull the data for '2018-03-01' from the sample table above, the return should be:

```
  country   | date       | budget
===================================
| Argentina | 2018-02-01 | $100
| Brazil    | 2018-03-01 | $430
| Colombia  | 2018-02-01 | $100
| Chile     | 2018-03-01 | $75
```

I'd like to avoid using the 'latest date' idea (query always returning the latest existing date for each country), as the new budgets could be added to the table before the current month end.

I'm trying to find a way to get it done in a single query, but if that's not possible, multiple are fine.

I'm using PHP7 to send queries to MariaDB.

Thanks for any contribution!

Comment: "I'd like to avoid using the 'latest date' idea (query always returning the latest existing date for each country),"  why? it looks like your expected result has the latest existing date and budget for each country

Comment: Thanks @Raymond Nijland. If I need to see the data for Feb ('2018-02-01') while I've already added budgets for March ('2018-03-01') for some countries, it will return wrong budgets, if it always returns the latest data. The query should first check if the requested date exists ('2018-02-01') for the given country, and only if it doesn't - use the previous month's budgets. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a filtering problem.   You want the row whose date is at or just before the given date:

```
select b.*
from budgets b
where b.date = (select max(b2.date)
                from budgets b2
                where b2.country = b.country and
                      b2.date <= '2018-03-01'
               );
```

In a database of countries and months, performance is probably not that big an issue.  But if it is, you want an index on `budgets(country, date)`.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff, this query works! I gotta be honest - my current MySQL knowledge is not good enough to fully understand the mechanics of this query, but it clearly works. Guess I'll need to hit the books some more :)